# Why my MacBook Pro is so slow?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, performance

I have a MacBook Pro Mid 2012 (MacBook Pro 9,2). Few years ago I was using previous versions of Mac OS X, and it was a great experience. I've found it delicious OS for personal use.

Today I use Yosemite and performance really slows down. Safari takes about 15 seconds to open, and 5 seconds to be ready for use. Terminal takes about 7 seconds to open.

I don't see the reason to buy new hardware, because i don't see any advantages in Yosemite. It has more simple design, but it works **much** more slowly. Okay, in theory I can receive cell calls on my MacBook Pro. But it takes about 10 seconds to show incoming call and to make it possible to click "answer".

I've removed all applications from automatic boot. I've cleared my HDD. I've tried almost everything and there were no results! It still works very slow!

Today I've tried Yosemite on the same hardware (Core i5, etc.) and it works really fast. Two differences are: it was Mac Mini and it was late 2014 model. I don't believe that Safari or something else requires new hardware to work normally. It seems like Apple just force me to buy new hardware. I guess in a year my MacBook will work like a turtle!?

So what can I do to improve my MacBook performance?

Comment: The only thig I would recommend is to upgrade to SSD drive. I had MacBook Pro mid 2010 and after changing the drive it was 100x faster. It's still amazingly fast with only 4GB of RAM.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek yes I thought about it. But it means that I have to buy new hardware again... Apple forces me to do it.

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev It's impossible for us to say what exactly is wrong with your setup and whether the problem is really Yosemite's increases power hunger, in which case your statement would make sense. But the investment for a more future-proof computer is not so substantial. Just get a smaller SSD (< 100$) and make a dual drive setup. Plus some more RAM (probably also < 50$) and it should be acceptable for a few more years.

Comment: I've installed Yosemite on an external drive and have been using it now and then with my MacBook Pro 5,3 from mid 2009 (regular HDD, no SSD btw). I had none of the issues described. So I think there's an underlying issue with the symptoms you are seeing. It is not related to Apple forcing you to buy more nor is it related to turtles.

Comment: Ah, and additionally: could you please show what diagnostic actions you have performed and what the results were? This will help narrow down the problem and makes providing a solution easier.

Answer (score 2):

While trialling Yosemite here at school I found the overall experience can vary wildly depending on how the installation is performed.

Most people will perform an upgrade installation by downloading the Yosemite installer and simply letting it run. The end result here is very variable and largely depends on the state of the system being upgraded. One or two of our teaching staff here have upgraded this way (against our advice) and have experienced various performance issues.

The other (better) way is to first back the system up using Time Machine and then make a USB Yosemite installer. Boot from the USB installer, run Disk Utility to erase the existing partitions and then perform a proper *clean* installation. You'll end up with a completely fresh installation which should run nicely, and you'll then have the option of restoring whatever you need from the Time Machine backup. Here at school we use DeployStudio for imaging and deploying to our Macs, and teachers using our "clean" build of Yosemite have fewer issues than those performing and upgrade of the existing OS.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have already check through "Activity Monitor" and made sure that there isn't anything that severely uses your resources.

After that, you can run some benchmarks and compare the MBP and the Mini (you said they had the same hw?)

Specifically you should check CPU, RAM and Hard Drive performance.

If other mid-2012 MBP are running fine with Yosemite, then it could be the hard drive dying.

Also, backup just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Although everyone here made great and thoughtful suggestions, it's very difficult to know what's causing the slowdown from afar. One thing you could do is download the latest EtreCheck and run it to see if there are other potential reasons for the slowdown. A fair number of 3rd-party apps out there leave detritus on your system that can slow your Mac to a crawl. Worth checking out, and the best part is, it's free. Also, note that an update (10.10.2) just posted and it resolved virtually all lag on my ancient 2009 Unibody. Hopefully it will help you, as well. Good luck!